# NgRx select cannot read property of undefined

Tags: angular, ngrx

I am trying to retrieve the state for my application using NgRx but I cannot get it to work. I get the error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'machines')
```

the error points to here in the selector below. I can add the ? operator, that causes the issue to go away but nothing render on the front end when i use the async pipe
machine.selector.ts

```
export const selectMachines = (state: AppState) => state.machineState;
export const selectAllMachines = createSelector(
  selectMachines,
  (state) => state.machines
);
```

how I select the machines in my component

```
  public allDevices$ = this.store.select(selectAllMachines);
```

machine reducer and state

```
export interface AppState {
machineState: MachinesState;
}


export interface MachinesState {
machines: Machine[];
}

const initialState: MachinesState = {
machines: [
  { id: '1', name: 'WASHER #1', status: Status.Available, type: 'Washer' },
  {
    id: '2',
    name: 'WASHER #2',
    status: Status.UnAvailable,
    type: 'Washer',
    user: 'Flat 4',
  },
  { id: '3', name: 'DRYER #1', status: Status.Available, type: 'Dryer' },
  {
    id: '4',
    name: 'DRYER #2',
    status: Status.UnAvailable,
    type: 'Dryer',
    user: 'Flat 1',
  },
],
};

export const machineReducer = createReducer(
initialState,
on(updateMachine, (state, { machine }) => {
  const index = state.machines.findIndex((d) => d.id === machine.id);
  state.machines[index] = machine;
  return state;
}),
on(getMachines, (state) => {
  return state;
})
);
```

Comment: 1) Probably your selector is firing before the state is initialized. Is your machines state lazy loaded? 2) likely unrelated but you are mutating your state in the first reducer case, you need to return a new object (use spread operator)

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
public allDevices$ = this.store.select(selectAllMachines);
```

should be in `ngOnInit`

something like

```
import * as machineSelector from '../location-of-your-machine-selector';

export class YourComponent implements OnInit {
   public allDevices$: Observable<Machine[]>;

   constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) {}

   ngOnInit(): void {
     this.allDevices$ = this.store.select(machineSelector.selectAllMachines);
   }
}
```

because its an async operation its a good idea to add an `ngIf` to the html to make sure the `machines` are loaded

```
<div class="container" *ngIf="allDevices$ | async as machines">
  <div *ngFor="let machine of machines">{{machine.name}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: To elaborate on the technical side of this, you can't use the state before `ngOnInit` because Angular hasn't injected your `Store` dependency yet.

Answer (score 0):

The way we set up our ngrx selectors is as follows:

- Define a constant variable name for the reducer, ex: `export const MY_CONSTANT = 'whatever'`
- In your selectors, create a feature selector as so: `const getViewState = createFeatureSelector<IParticipantViewState>(MY_CONSTANT );`
- In your module define the following for the store, along with its reducer:
         `StoreModule.forFeature(MY_CONSTANT , machineReducer , { initialState: myState}),`

where myState is defined `myState as initialState` which is imported from your reducer file where the initial state is set up.

This way we wirte up the store module for our particular feature, with a default reducer and an initialState set up. The feature selector gives us the slice that we need.

Finally, in your `createSelector` it will look like what you made except you will pass in the `getViewState` variable as the first argument.